# Issue on responsive small devicebelow 370px white space on the right with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

Hello I have downloaded a free template bootstrap that seemed to be fully responsive on https://startbootstrap.com/previews/freelancer but when I have downloaded it, for very small devices I have a white space on small devices below 370px.
I have used this template and applied it for my own website that is not yet online and I am annoyed about this white space. Now the content is not centered on small devices below 370px but above 370px it looks fine. I have also used my own css. But I think it's primarly something to do with the bootstrap theme and the css rules within it. Can someone help me please?
[screenshot on mobile device below 370px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBiUP.png)

```
enter code here<!-- Section status-->
```

## Webmaster.

```
  <div class="text-center mt-4">
    <a class="btn btn-xl btn-outline-light" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-download mr-2"></i>
        Mon cv!
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

OLIVIA
      
      
        
         
           Bienvenue, etc 
      
        
       
      
      
        
            
            Mon cv!
        
    
      
  
  
  


  
  Prestations

#### Gestion de projets web

text. 
           text.
           text.
           text

```
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto"> <h3>Administration web</h3><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point"> text</p><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point"> text.</p><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point">text. </p><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point">text</p></div>
    
   
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    
  <div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto"> <h3>CRM, emailing</h3><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point">text</p><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point">text.</p><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point">text.</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 ml-auto"> <h3>Création de sites internet</h3><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point">text</p><p class="lead"><img src="images/bullet.png" alt="point">text</p></div>
</div>
```

Mes créations de sites web

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center" >
      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-5"> <img class="image-portfolio" src="images/icone-reseaux-sociaux.png" alt="personnages" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><img  class="image-portfolio" src="images/icone-chariot.png" alt="icone d'un chariot de supermarché" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 mb-5"> <img class="image-portfolio" src="images/icone-lunettes-de-soleil.png" alt="gants de boxe" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal3"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-3"><img  class="image-portfolio" src="images/icone-gants-de-boxe.png" alt="voiture" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal4"></div>
    </div>
```

Me contacter

```
  <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
              <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="#">

                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm col-xs">
                          <label for="firstname">Prénom <span class="pink">*</span></label>
                          <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"  class="form-control" placeholder="Votre prénom">
                          <p class="comments"> </p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="name">Nom<span class="pink"> *</span></label>
                          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre nom">
                          <p class="comments"></p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="email">Email<span class="pink"> *</span></label>
                          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre email">
                          <p class="comments"></p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="phone">Téléphone</label>
                          <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre numéro de téléphone">
                          <p class="comments"></p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <label for="message">Message<span class="pink"> *</span></label>
                          <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre message" rows="2"></textarea>
                          <p class="comments"></p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12">
                      <input type="checkbox" name="consentement" class="form-check-input" id="verif" value="Optin">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="verif">En remplissant ce formulaire, j'accepte que mes données personnelles soient utilisées pour me recontacter dans le cadre de ma demande indiquée dans ce formulaire. Aucun autre traitement ne sera effectué avec mes informations<span class="pink"> *</span><br> <small> Pour connaître et exercer vos droits, notamment de retrait de votre consentement à l'utilisation des données collectées par ce formulaire, veuillez consulter notre politique de confidentialité </small></label>
                      <p class="comments"></p>
                      <div id="error"></div>

                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <p class="pink"><strong>* Ces informations sont requises</strong></p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input type="submit" class="button1" value="Envoyer">
                      </div>
                      
                  </div>

                  

              </form>



          </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: If you want your column to cover the whole width on a small device (i.e. smartphone), try giving the column classes of `col-12 col-md-6` — that would give you a full width column on phones and a half page width column on tablets. It’s difficult to say any more without seeing enough code to reproduce the problem (not just an image).

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I had to my website online so you can see https://www.oantonin.fr/

Comment: Your image at the top, which is 480px wide, stays the same width, so when the display is less than around 500px wide, you’re getting a horizontal scrollbar, which can cause a blank space on the right. Try adding Bootstrap’s img-fluid class to your image. That will set the max-width to 100%.

Comment: Thank you very much for having a look on my website. i did try out what you mentioned in the inspector developer tool , I have added the class 'img-fluid' to the image but the white margin is still there.

Comment: In your style.css file, at line 338, you’re setting the left and right padding to 5px. What happens if you change that to 0?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think you have helped me a lot to understand better some responsive complexities :)